# how to set ENV variable in windows CMD line

Tags: windows, shell

I'd like to set a temporary enviroment variable in windows CMD line, which in my word the windows shell. because it's for temporary usage, So I don't want to add a new enviroment variable system wise by clicking "my computer-->properies---" ...

by the way, the envrioment variable I'd like to set is http proxy, but I don't known the windows syntax for that. so if you happen to know it as well, please tell me and I'll apreciate you even more ...

Answer (score 54):

To set a temporary or 'per session' environment varible from a command line you can use:

`set ‹var name›=‹value>`

Make sure your spacing is exactly as shown above, if you add a space between the equal sign the command will fail.

Check: [Link](http://xahlee.info/mswin/env_var.html) for a nice tutorial and info on environment variables.

Comment: It's not so much per session as per process and child process. Other processes already running in your login session will *not* see this new (or changed) variable, only the current `cmd.exe` process and any processes launched from it.

Comment: Sorry, with session I meant the current process; I just noticed that calling it session may be a bit confusing.

Comment: It's interesting to note that variable names may contain spaces (at least with this method), so if you add a space, that gets added to the variable name. Strange.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using PowerShell, then you need to use the $env prefix for creating an environment variable.

Here's an example:

```
$env:<var name> = '<value>'
```

Comment: Question state "windows CMD line", not PowerShell

Answer (score 10):

```
SET VAR_NAME=value
```

See the [Microsoft Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490998(v=technet.10)) for the details.